# Pagination sort link on a virtual field/entity property in CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, pagination, virtual, jquery-ui-sortable, paginator

I want to create a [pagination sort link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-sort-links) on a [virtual field/entity property](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties) in CakePHP 3.0.

In CakePHP 2.x I used to create a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html), and then create a pagination sort link on that field. However, in CakePHP 3.0, [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) have been replaced by [virtual entity properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties).

Is there any way I can get this working in CakePHP 3.0?

In my situation, I have a first_name and last_name column, which are combined as full_name in a [virtual entity property](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties). I want to sort on the full_name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As stated in the linked docs, virtual properties cannot be used in finds. That's by design, virtual properties only live in entities, they are built in PHP *after* data has been retrieved from the database.

So let's forget about virtual properties for a moment, and concentrate on queries and computed columns.

### Computed columns need to be specified via `sortWhitelist`

Just like columns of associated models, computed columns need to be specified in the `sortWhitelist` option in order to be useable for sorting!

**[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Control which Fields Used for Ordering](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)**

#### Via pagination options

You have some options here, for example you could define computed columns in the pagination options:

```php
$this->paginate = [
    // ...
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'full_name',
        // ...
    ],
    'fields' => [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'full_name' => $this->Table->query()->func()->concat([
            'first_name' => 'literal',
            'last_name' => 'literal'
        ]),
        // ...
    ],
    'order' => [
        'full_name' => 'DESC'
    ]
];
```

#### A custom finder

Another, more reusable option would be to use a custom finder:

```php
$this->paginate = [
    // ...
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'full_name',
        // ...
    ],
    'finder' => 'withFullName',
    'order' => [
        'full_name' => 'DESC'
    ]
];
```

```php
public function findWithFullName(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->select([
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'full_name' => $query->func()->concat([
            'first_name' => 'literal',
            'last_name' => 'literal'
        ]),
        // ...
    ]);
}
```

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Pagination > Using Controller::paginate()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#using-controller-paginate)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**

#### Separate custom query

It's also possible to directly pass query objects to `Controller::paginate()`:

```php
$this->paginate = [
    // ...
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'full_name',
        // ...
    ],
    'order' => [
        'full_name' => 'DESC'
    ]
];

$query = $this->Table
    ->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'full_name' => $query->func()->concat([
                'first_name' => 'literal',
                'last_name' => 'literal'
            ]),
            // ...
        ];
    });
$results = $this->paginate($query);
```

Comment: I will take a look into this (probably tomorrow). I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your default sort order to be the same as your virtual field:

```
public $paginate = [
  'order' => [
    'first_name' => 'ASC',
    'last_name' => 'ASC',
  ]
];
```

Then just add the following to your View to prevent the paginator from overriding the default order unless specified by the user:

```
if (empty($_GET['direction'])) { $this->Paginator->options(['url' => ['direction' => null, 'sort' => null]]); }
```