# Why won't CakePHP 3.2 Paginator sort on my query results?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

CakePHP query and such from the controller:

```
$ratings = $this->Ratings->find('all')->group('manufacturer');
$ratings->select(['manufacturer',
                  'count' => $ratings->func()->count('*'),
                  'max' => $ratings->func()->max('psi_score'),
                  'min' => $ratings->func()->min('psi_score')]);
$ratings = $this->paginate($ratings);
$this->set(compact('ratings'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['ratings']);
```

Here is what `debug($ratings)` produces:

```
'items' => [
    (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

        'manufacturer' => 'A10Green Technology',
        'count' => (int) 8,
        'max' => '7.41',
        'min' => '6.57',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Ratings'

    },
```

In the view, sorting on `manufacturer` works fine. That is an original db field. The `count`, `max` and `min` values are not getting sorted.

Here are the `sort` calls for the view:

```
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('manufacturer')?></th>
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('count')?></th>
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('max')?></th>
<th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('max')?></th>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763413/pagination-sort-link-on-a-virtual-field-entity-property-in-cakephp-3-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist the fields that you want to allow to be sorted like in: [Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)

```
public $paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id', 'title', 'Users.username', 'created'
    ]
];
```

Otherwise by default cake 3 blocks it