# Paginate and Sort bug(s)?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.2

In my controller I have my pagination set to order by 2 fields.

```
public $paginate = [
  'limit' => 50,
  'order' => ['first_name', 'last_name']
];
$contacts = $this->paginate($this->Contacts);
```

This works fine on the first page, but since I left out the default direction `=> 'ASC'`  the Paginator links don't work at all:

```
/contacts?page=2&sort=0&direction=first_name
```

When I add in the direction, it works, but of course only sorts by the first field, messing up the sort order.

```
/contacts?page=2&sort=Contacts.first_name&direction=ASC
```

1. Should the default direction be explicitly required?
2. Is there a method to maintain both fields for sorting during pagination?

Sorting by virtual fields (e.g. `full_name => first_name . ' ' . last_name`) doesn't work as it did in 2.x

Comment: Where is the code you're using to create your links?

Comment: Default baked code: `<div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?php echo $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
    </div>`

Comment: 1. Yes, it should. 2. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763413/pagination-sort-link-on-a-virtual-field-entity-property-in-cakephp-3-0

Comment: I think this is a [known issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7324).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved both issues with the following:

Set the default sort order to be the same as the virtual field:

```
public $paginate = [
  'order' => ['first_name', 'last_name']
];
```

Then just add the following to the View to prevent the paginator from overriding the default order unless specified by the user:

```
if (empty($_GET['direction'])) { $this->Paginator->options(['url' => ['direction' => null, 'sort' => null]]); }
```