# Paginate sort on subquery column in CakePHP 3

Tags: sorting, cakephp, subquery, cakephp-3.x

This might be answered somewhere else already, but I was looking for an answer the past few days and couldn't find an answer that suited my problem/that I understood...

I'm using CakePHP 3.8.5 and am currently working on a query that includes a subquery in the select.
I got 3 tables `Locations`, `Computers` and `Printers`. `Locations` and `Computers` are in a `belongsToMany` relationship, as well as `Locations` and `Printers`.

So I'm trying to get the following query, which is working well as far as the data results go:

```
    $computersQuery = $this->Computers->find();
    $computersQuery->select([$computersQuery->func()->count('*')])
        ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) {
            return $exp
                ->notEq('Computers.Unwanted_Software', '')
                ->equalFields('Computers.Area_ID', 'Locations.Area_ID');
        });
        
    $printersQuery = $this->Printers->find();
    $printersQuery->select($printersQuery->func()->count('*'))
        ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) {           
            return $exp
                ->eq('Printers.WHQL', 0)
                ->equalFields('Printers.Area_ID', 'Locations.Area_ID');
        });
    
    $dataQuery = $this->Locations->find();
    $dataQuery->select(['Locations.Area_ID',
            'Unwanted_Software' => $computersQuery,
            'Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible' => $printersQuery])
        ->group('Locations.Area_ID');
```

So I'm trying to paginate the `$dataQuery` in my Controller. In my model I can click all three column headers but only the `Area_ID` column will get sorted. The two subquery columns won't sort. Even tho I'm not getting Errors.
Looking at the SQL-log shows that it's never even trying to `order by` those two columns...

Any ideas how to fix this/work around this are highly appreciated!

If you need more info about my code just leave a comment below.

**EDIT 1:**

As user @ndm pointed out, I had to put the computed fields into the `sortWhitelist` option of the pagination array.
Doing that worked out well as I was able to sort by the column headers:

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'limit' => '100',
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Locations.Area_ID',
            'Unwanted_Software',
            'Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible'
        ],
        'order' => ['Locations.Area_ID' => 'ASC']
    ]
```

But then the next problem appeared. Was trying to sort by the `Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible` column. The generated SQL code had one small issue (BTW I'm using SQL Server 2008):

```
    SELECT * 

    FROM (SELECT Locations.Area_ID AS [Locations__Area_ID], 
    (SELECT (COUNT(*)) FROM computers Computers WHERE (...)) AS [Unwanted_Software], 
    (SELECT (COUNT(*)) FROM printers Printers WHERE (...)) AS [Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible], 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SELECT (COUNT(*)) FROM printers Printers WHERE (...) asc, Locations.Area_ID ASC)) AS [_cake_page_rownum_] FROM locations_Views Locations GROUP BY Locations.Area_ID ) _cake_paging_ 

    WHERE _cake_paging_._cake_page_rownum_ <= 100
```

This represents the generated SQL code. Problem is that in de `Order By` statement there are no brackets around my subquery. It should look like this, so that SQL Server can read it:

```
    ... ORDER BY ( SELECT (COUNT(*)) FROM printers Printers WHERE (...) ) asc, ...
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT 2:**

So @ndm answer with either the pull-request or the fix via the `newExpr()` function both work great. At least regarding the parentheses for the subquery in the `Order By`.

Sadly already running into the next problem. The generated SQL (this counts for both solutions!) is kinda "refreshing" the parameter input for the entire query in the `Order By`, which means that it puts the filter parameters for the `Where` clauses in starting again by parameter `:c0`. You can see that in the following query:

```
SELECT * 

FROM (SELECT Locations.Area_ID AS [Locations__Area_ID], 
(SELECT (COUNT(*)) 
    FROM computers Computers 
    WHERE (Computers.Unwanted_Software != :c0 
    AND Computers.Area_ID = (Locations.Area_ID)
    )
) AS [Unwanted_Software], 
(SELECT (COUNT(*)) 
    FROM printers Printers 
    WHERE (Printers.WHQL = :c1 
    AND Printers.Area_ID = (Locations.Area_ID))
) AS [Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible], 
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    (SELECT (COUNT(*)) 
        FROM printers Printers 
        WHERE (Printers.WHQL = :c0 
        AND Printers.Area_ID = (Locations.Area_ID))) asc,
    Locations.Area_ID ASC)
) AS [_cake_page_rownum_] 

FROM locations_Views Locations 

GROUP BY Locations.Area_ID ) _cake_paging_ 

WHERE _cake_paging_._cake_page_rownum_ <= 100
```

I don't think this is the intended result. I personally can probably work around that, by avoiding passing parameters directly (I don't have to deal with concrete external user input). Still think this should be looked over.

Thanks @ndm for great help! Definitely an upvote from me.

Comment: Sounds like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763413/pagination-sort-link-on-a-virtual-field-entity-property-in-cakephp-3-0**. By default sorting is only allowed on the primary repository's columns.

Comment: @ndm I updated my question, as your help got me a bit further towards the solution but it appears that there are still small errors. Hope you can help me out on that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As linked in the comments, by default the paginator only allows sorting on columns that exist in the main table, columns of other tables (joins) or computed columns [**must be explicitly allowed via the `sortWhiteList` option**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763413/pagination-sort-link-on-a-virtual-field-entity-property-in-cakephp-3-0).

The missing parentheses in the the generated window function SQL looks like a bug, [**the SQL Server query translator**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.9.4/src/Database/Dialect/SqlserverDialectTrait.php#L118-L123) doesn't check whether the expression that is defined in the `order` clause is a query, which would require to wrap the generated SQL in parentheses.

I've pushed a possible fix for `3.9` and `4.1`:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15165**
**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15164**

If you cannot upgrade right now, a possible workaround could be to wrap your subqueries in additional expressions, which when compiled should wrap the inner query expression in parentheses:

```php
$dataQuery
    ->select([
        'Locations.Area_ID',
        'Unwanted_Software' => $dataQuery->newExpr($computersQuery),
        'Printers_Not_WHQL_Compatible' => $dataQuery->newExpr($printersQuery)
    ])
    ->group('Locations.Area_ID');
```

Comment: Thanks! really helped me a lot! Edited the question once more since i think there isn't everything fixed, but still thumbs up! :)

Comment: @Yama Yeah, that doesn't look right, I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: @Yama So that turned out to be a bit more tricky, I've created a PR with an idea for a possible fix, but I'm not sure about possible side effects. Maybe you can give it a try, and if you can, add some feedback over at GitHub: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/15166**